# Visual Studio update changed default language

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Just updated Visual Studio today to version 16.6.2 today. Now, when going to File -> New -> File, it defaults to Visual Basic instead of C#. I went to Tools -> Import and Export Settings and reset all my setting to see if that would fix it... It didn't. It still defaults to Visual Basic for new files. Obviously, it didn't do that before I updated. Does anyone know any other settings to change my default back to C#?

[image]

Comment: Anyone?... Anyone? .... Bueller? .... Bueller?

Comment: Could you share me with some screenshots? I suggest you close VS and try to delete or rename the hidden .vs folder which is located in your solution folder currently, and check if this fixes this issue. BTW, I need to confirm this with you, do you mean “File > New > File…” or “File > New > Project…”?

Comment: It is File>New>File. I'm adding a lot of new .aspx files to an existing project. Eliminating the .vs directory didn't help.

Comment: Did you perform some actions before, such as installing VB related workload or components? I think this is by design and every time you click File > New > File VS will default to the first(top) item of “Installed”(for you is Visual Basic).

Comment: No, just the update. I've never used VB and don't plan to, so any extra VB stuff I ignore. If I could uninstall any and all VB components, that would be fine with me.